# Building a new Maven Project with existing javascript files

Tags: javascript, maven, project

I am having some issues beginning a new maven project. The tutorials I have watched have been useful but I feel like I am missing something and need some clarification.

- My project consists purely of javascript files. It is all objective and developed to be used as and when rather than use on a single website. The main HTML and CSS which was developed along with the javascript is a separate Maven project.
- There are pre minified files such as the `jquery-1.9.1`, `jquery-ui-1.10.3` and `modernizr`
- There are 6 javascript files of my own;

  - 1 main file which must be included first
  - 4 more files which require a number of the methods/functions and global variables from the main file
  - 1 last .js file which is dependant on one of the files in the previous point (and therefore has two dependancies)

The specs of the Maven project require;

- Creating documentation of the files.
- Unit testing - perhaps with [Jasmine](http://searls.github.io/jasmine-maven-plugin/)
- Obfuscate all javascript code

I have been looking at the following but need a bit of help in steps to begin the project. When I jslint one of the files there is obviously many bugs because `$` is not defined and many of the functions and variables are declared in seperate files.

- [MOJO - Codehaus](http://mojo.codehaus.org/javascript-maven-tools/javascript-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html)
- [akquinet](http://blog.akquinet.de/2011/02/11/mavenizing-javascript-projects/)
- [yuicompressor](http://alchim.sourceforge.net/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/usage_compress.html)

Thanks in advance.